# very noisy Tweetbot messages in Console app (GUI) - where is the log location on disk (path)?

Tags: command-line, macos, logs, tweetbot

Tweetbot generates very much log entries (debug log?) in Console.app.

[image]

What's the source of those logs? I didn't find a Tweetbot log file.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of comments. Your screencap does not show the sidebar which will generally show the path to the log in question (EG "/Library/Logs" etc.). Also when you select the log to view on one of the left-hand columns you can select FILE > REVEAL IN FINDER to show the actual log file itself in Finder.